# Ubuntu Touch on SII phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung

I have the Samsung Galaxy SII Straight Talk phone. I want to install Ubuntu Touch. The model is different from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9100

Should it still work with my phone?

Comment: No your phone model is SGH-S959G, that ROM is for the GT-i9100.

Comment: They said the same thing about using an AJK kernel, but here I am using it. I've found that my phone model is for what ever reason mistaken for an AT&T phone even though it is clearly from straight talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a Cyanogenmod 10.1 build for the GT-i9100, you (in theory) can run ubuntu touch. I believe what you have to do is first flash [CM 10.1](http://get.cm/) (ubuntu is a chroot in CM) in recovery mode and then flash "[raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip)." Be sure to do a factory reset before wiping and you must a compatible recover such as [TWRP](http://www.teamw.in/project/twrp2) or [CWM](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager).

**Hint: use the [i777](http://get.cm/?device=i777) build of CyanogenMod

Comment: I will try this tonight when I get home